# How to recursively loop through a file structure and rename directories in python

Tags: python, rename, directory

I would like to resursively rename directories by changing the last character to lowercase (if it is a letter)

I have done this with the help of my previous posts (sorry for the double posting and not acknowledging the answers)

This code works for Files, but how can I adapt it for directories as well?

```
import fnmatch
import os


def listFiles(dir):
    rootdir = dir
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            yield os.path.join(root,file)
    return


for f in listFiles(r"N:\Sonstiges\geoserver\IM_Topo\GIS\MAPTILEIMAGES_0\tiles_2"):
    if f[-5].isalpha():
        os.rename(f,f[:-5]+f[-5].lower() + ".JPG")
        print "Renamed " +  "---to---" + f[:-5]+f[-5].lower() + ".JPG"
```

Comment: Please try to avoid adding extraneous comments and signatures to posts.

Comment: One problem you might run into is that renaming a directory while you're walking the tree can cause the walk to fail (since you might try to walk into a directory that's been renamed). So what you might want to do is make a list of all the directories that need renamed, and have a separate loop after the walk to rename those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the default of [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) is topdown. If you try to rename directories while traversing topdown, the results are unpredictable.

Try setting `os.walk` to go bottom up:

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir,topdown=False):
```

**Edit**

Another problem you have is `listFiles()` is returning, well, files not directories.

This (untested) sub returns directories from bottom up:

```
def listDirs(dir):
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(dir, topdown=False):
        for folder in subFolders:
           yield os.path.join(root,folder)
    return
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don´t know how I can change the code to rename only the directories and not the files though. I have substituted listFiles with listDirs but that doesn´t work.  Cheers, Rob

Comment: Use `subFolders` instead of `files`. `files` is a list of the files, `subFolders` a list of the subdirectories.